# Button not displaying in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website http://news.homepage119.biz/. I have created two buttons in my website which i have fixed at bottom of page and that i want to use to toggle between desktop and mobile mode of my website. But, the button is not displaying when i view it actually on mobile while it shows on resizing the browser window. Please can you help me to solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET['w'] == 'm') {
    $_SESSION['mobilemode'] = 'true';
}

if($_GET['w'] == 'pc') {
    $_SESSION['mobilemode'] = 'false';
}

?>
<!doctype html >

<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]--><head>

<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' );?>" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>  

<?php global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request)); ?> 



<script type="text/javascript">

var cururl = window.location.href;
if(cururl == 'http://news.homepage119.biz/?w=m'){
    window.location.replace("http://news.homepage119.biz");
}

else if((cururl == 'http://news.homepage119.biz/?w=pc')){
    window.location.replace("http://news.homepage119.biz");
}

</script>






<?php
if($_SESSION['mobilemode'] == 'true') {
    /* MOBILE MODE */
    ?>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <style type="text/css">
                .mobbtn{display: none}
        .deskbtn{display: block;background: #333;text-align: center;width: 100%;position: fixed;z-index: 1000000000;bottom: -1px;padding:10px;}

    </style>
    <?php
} else {
    // DEFAULT
    ?>
    <meta name="viewport">
    <style type="text/css">
        .deskbtn{display:none;}
        .mobbtn{display: block;background: #333;text-align: center;width: 100%;position: fixed;z-index: 1000000000;bottom: -1px;padding:10px;}
    <?php
}
?>


<?php

    wp_head(); /** we hook up in wp_booster @see td_wp_booster_functions::hook_wp_head */

?>
<style>
@media(min-width:768px){
.deskbtn{display:none}
.mobbtn{display:none}
}
</style>
</head>





<body <?php body_class() ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="<?php echo td_global::$http_or_https?>://schema.org/WebPage">
<a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>/?w=m" class="mobbtn">Switch to Mobile View</a><a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>/?w=pc" class="deskbtn">Switch to Desktop View</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a css or device issue, not php.

I notice that AFTER you use php to output the style for mobbtn based upon $_SESSION['mobilemode'] you then use static css to change the style to display:none

css reads from top-down and your second declaration of display:none will replace your more dynamic assignment. As written, if your window width is 768px or greater, none of the buttons will show at all in either mode. mobile devices do not normally have a width greater than 768 but maybe yours is reporting that way.

also your current live code is using ?w=pc for desktop instead of ?w=w so I'm now stuck in mobile mode

Comment: It's my mistake that it needed to be 'pc'. So, is there any way through which i can fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem on my device. I'm curious if removing this code will make it work properly on your device?

`<style>
@media(min-width:768px){
.deskbtn{display:none}
.mobbtn{display:none}
}
</style>`